# geometic description of vector span

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

i am having some poblem with this question 
Show that the set if vector is linearly dependant. If the vector span a line, provide the equation of the line. If the vector span a plane, provide the equation of the plane
S = {(1,0,1), (1,1,0), (5,2,3)}

this is what did so far:
the third vector = 3(first vector) + 2(second vector). Therefore they are linearly dependent. At least two of the vector are non parallel, therefore they soan the plane containing the. the third vecto is the linear combination of the other two vector, so the span of all three vector is the span of the other two
is what i did correct? can anyone explain how to write the equation of the plane?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you have said is correct. To find an equation for the plane spanned by 
$(1,0,1),(1,1,0)$, we use the equation $\vec{n} \cdot (\vec{p}-\vec{p_0})$ where n is a normal vector and $\vec{p}=(x,y,z)$ and $\vec{p_0}$ is some point on your plane.

First find the normal vector using the cross product and find

$(1,0,1)\times (1,1,0)=(-1,1,1)=\vec{n}$, then take $\vec{p_0}=(1,0,1)$, which better be in your plane since it is definitely in the span of the first vector, and compute away.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the span of the vectors $(1,0,1),(1,1,0),(5,2,3)$. As you correctly mentioned, the third vector is a linear combination of the first two. The dimension of the vector space spanned by these three vectors is 2, and so the span of these three vectors is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  We want its equation.

The span of the three given vectors is equal to the span of the first two, which is equal to $\{ a (1,0,1) + b (1,1,0): a,b \in \mathbb{R} \} = \{ (a+b,b,a): a,b \in \mathbb{R} \}$. Denote the third coordinate by $z$ and the second coordinate by $y$.  So $z=a$ and $y=b$.  We get that the first coordinate $x$ is $x=a+b=y+z$.  The equation of the hyperplane is $x=y+z$.